# Pantalla negra al ejecutar Pygame

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pygame

Previamente a formular esta pregunta cabe destacar que he consultado varias fuentes buscando alguna respuesta a mi problema. Ninguna de ellas parece haber servido. A pesar de intentar resolver mi problema por mi cuenta, releyendo el código, el error sigue existiendo.

Acá mi código:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
#abajo se encuentra el fondo de la ventana
#ventana.fill(ColorDos)
pygame.display.set_caption("Retouch")

Mi_imagen = pygame.image.load("Image/meflag.png")
Imagen_Dos = pygame.image.load("Image/Kool-Aid.gif")
posX= randint (100, 300)
posY = randint (101, 200)

velocidad=4
Color = (66, 133 ,244)#Azul
ColorDos = pygame.Color(244, 180, 0)#Amarillo
ColorTres = (244,67,54)#Rojo
ColorCuatro = (0,135,68) #verde
derecha=True

rectangulo = pygame.Rect(0,0,100,50)
print posY, posX

# Color = (244,180,0)
#primero donde, despues, color(tupla u objeto), tupla de cordenadas en X, Y. El ultimo parametro es el tamano del radio.
pygame.draw.circle(ventana, Color, (200, 300), 500)
"""Primero donde, despues que color, despues tupla con cuatro valores.
Los primeros dos valores (X,Y) son la esquina izquierda superior.
El tercer valor es el ancho de nuestro rectangulo.
Y el cuarto valor es el alto del rectangulo:"""
pygame.draw.rect(ventana, ColorCuatro,(100,100,100,50) )
"""Primero donde, despues color, despues el tercer parametro es una tupla con tuplas dentro de esta.
Dentro de esa tupla se encuentras las cordenadas, posiciones (X,Y) de los puntos que al final pygame une."""
pygame.draw.polygon(ventana, ColorTres, ((80,90),(200,400), (80,10))  )


while True:
    ventana.fill(ColorDos)
    # ventana.blit(Mi_imagen,(posX, posY))  
    ventana.blit(Imagen_Dos,(posX, posY))
    pygame.draw.rect(ventana, ColorTres,rectangulo)
    rectangulo.left, rectangulo.top = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
"""Este de abajo mueve a Kool-Aid"""
# posX,posY=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
# posX=posX-100
# posY=posY-50

"""Lo de abajo(comentado) mueve la imagen sin parar"""
if derecha==True:
    if posX <400:
        posX+=velocidad
    else:
        derecha=False
else: 
    if posX>1:
        posX-=velocidad
    else:
        derecha=True

#       elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
#           if event.key == K_LEFT:
#               posX-=velocidad
#           elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
#               posX+=velocidad




pygame.display.update()
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este error (pantalla negra)?
¿Cómo puedo evitar esta clase de errores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un error, simplemente estás mostrando elementos en la pantalla pero no la estás actualizando.

Tienes que actualizar la pantalla en cada iteración. Esto lo consigues usando [`pygame.display.update()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update):

```
while True:
    # ...
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # ...
```

### Actualización

He notado que la llamada a la función la estabas usando en el lugar equivocado, debe estar dentro del *game loop* de tu programa, no afuera. Tal vez solo era un problema de indentación de tu código pero lo anterior debería funcionar.

Para que te sirva de guía, te dejo el enlace al código de un juego que hice hace algunos años, es un juego de memoria que espero te sirva:

- [Memoreek / src / memory.py](https://bitbucket.org/cesarbustios/memoreek/src/e474cc40a8df652d6e895852a0cee274f8f19952/src/memory.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Observa como toda la lógica del juego ocurre dentro del *game loop* y como uso las demás funciones para cambiar el estado del juego.

Comment: Gracias!
Tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda.